# Remove item PagedListAdapter, getting IndexOutOfBoundsException error second time I remove list item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I am removing an item in PagedListAdapter. I am not using room, simply I store a cached list `inMemoryElements` of all the elements I have loaded. When I remove one item, I just delete that item from the list, and then call DataSource.invalidate(), which calls again LoadInitialCallback.onResult() where I pass my cached list.

Everything works fine the first time I delete one item, but the second time I delete other item, I get:

> `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 18, Size: 18 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437) at androidx.paging.PagedStorage.get(PagedStorage.java:174) at androidx.paging.PagedStorageDiffHelper$1.areItemsTheSame(PagedStorageDiffHelper.java:77)`

Theese are my components:

1. In my Fragment, where I have the paginated RecyclerView, here I call the ViewModel method `makeCallGetArticleListPaging` for loading the elements into LiveData wrap. I then call function `getPagedList` for subscribing to `LiveData<PagedList<ArticleDto>>` values.
2. In DataSourceFactory: I have a reference of current datasource for calling .invalidate()
3. Reposiroty: where I create the pagedList.
4. Finally when item is deleted, I call ViewModel method `invalidateDatasource()`

DataSource:

```
public class ArticleDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, ArticleDto> {

 ApiService apiService;
 private List<ArticleDto> inMemoryElements;

 public ArticleDataSource(ApiService apiService, String apiServiceMethod, List<ArticleDto> inMemoryElements, int currentPage) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
    this.inMemoryElements = inMemoryElements;
    this.currentPage = currentPage;
}   


@Override
public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<Integer, ArticleDto> callback) {
    queryArticleDto.setPageIndex(currentPage);
    HashMap<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", HttpConstants.HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE);

    if(inMemoryElements.isEmpty()){
            apiService.search(headers,queryArticleDto).enqueue(new Callback<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>> call, Response<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>> response) {
                        inMemoryElements.addAll(response.body().getElements());
                        callback.onResult(response.body().getElements(), null, 1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>> call, Throwable t) {
                        callback.onResult(new ArrayList<>(), null, 0);
                }
            });
    }else{
        callback.onResult(inMemoryElements,null,currentPage + 1);
    }
}


@Override
public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadCallback<Integer, ArticleDto> callback) {
    int currentPage = params.key;
    queryArticleDto.setPageIndex(currentPage);
    apiService.search(headers,queryArticleDto).enqueue(new Callback<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>> call, Response<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                inMemoryElements.addAll(response.body().getElements());
                callback.onResult(response.body().getElements(), currentPage + 1);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PageResultDto<ArticleDto>> call, Throwable t) {
            callback.onResult(new ArrayList<>(), currentPage);
        }
    });
    
}
```

}

DataSourceFactory:

```
public class ArticleDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory<Integer, ArticleDto> {

//To perform network calls
private ApiService apiService;
private UserSessionLiveData userSessionLiveData;

private ArticleDto queryArticleDto;
private ArticleDataSource articleDataSource;

@Inject
public ArticleDataSourceFactory(ApiService apiService, UserSessionLiveData userSessionLiveData) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
    this.userSessionLiveData = userSessionLiveData;
}

public void setQueryArticleDto(ArticleDto queryArticleDto) {
    this.queryArticleDto = queryArticleDto;
    if(articleDataSource != null)
        articleDataSource.setQueryArticleDto(queryArticleDto);
}

public void setApiServiceMethod(String apiServiceMethod) {
    this.apiServiceMethod = apiServiceMethod;
}

//Factory method pattern implemented below
//Where a create method does the job of initializing the objects for client
@NonNull
@Override
public DataSource<Integer, ArticleDto> create() {
    articleDataSource = new ArticleDataSource(apiService,
            apiServiceMethod,
            userSessionLiveData,
            articleDataSource == null ? new ArrayList<>() : articleDataSource.getInMemoryElements(),
            articleDataSource == null ? 0 : articleDataSource.getCurrentPage()
    );
    articleDataSource.setQueryArticleDto(queryArticleDto);

    return articleDataSource;
}

public ArticleDataSource getArticleDataSource() {
    return articleDataSource;
}}
```

PagedList:

```
public class ArticleRepository {

   public LiveData<PagedList<ArticleDto>> getPagedList(ArticleDto articleDto, String apiServiceMethod) {

    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPageSize(5)
            .setPrefetchDistance(1)
            .setMaxSize(10)
            .build();

    return new LivePagedListBuilder<>(articleDataSourceFactory, config)
            .setFetchExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)) // Use five threads to do the fetching operations
            .build();

}}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ArticleViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final MutableLiveData<PagedList<ArticleDto>> _pagedList = new MutableLiveData<>();
private LiveData<PagedList<ArticleDto>> pagedList = (LiveData<PagedList<ArticleDto>>)  _pagedList;

public void makeCallGetArticleListPaging(ArticleDto articleDto, String apiServiceMethod){
    pagedList = articleRepository.getPagedList(articleDto,apiServiceMethod);
}

public LiveData<PagedList<ArticleDto>> getPagedList() {
    return pagedList;
}}
```

Fragment:

```
public class ArticleListFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    articleViewModel.makeCallGetArticleListPaging(articleDto, ArticleDataSource.API_SERVICE_METHOD_SEARCH);
    observeData();
}


private void observeData() {
    articleViewModel.getPagedList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<PagedList<ArticleDto>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(PagedList<ArticleDto> posts) {
            postsPagedListAdapter.submitList(posts);
        }
    });
}

public void invalidateDatasource(int rowPosition){
    articleDataSourceFactory.getArticleDataSource().getInMemoryElements().remove(rowPosition);
    articleDataSourceFactory.getArticleDataSource().invalidate();
}}
```

DiffUtil.ItemCallback

```
new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ArticleDto>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull ArticleDto oldItem, @NonNull ArticleDto newItem) {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull ArticleDto oldItem, @NonNull ArticleDto newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }
};
```